# With Gradle, is it possible to call GradleBuild directly instead of specifying it as a type?

Tags: gradle

I have this in my build.gradle:

```
task cleanCommon(type: GradleBuild) {
  buildFile = 'common/build.gradle'  
  tasks = ['clean']  
}

task cleanCrawler(type: GradleBuild) {
  buildFile = 'crawler/build.gradle'
  tasks = ['clean']
}

task cleanPortlet(type: GradleBuild) {
  buildFile = 'portlet/build.gradle'
  tasks = ['clean']
}

task cleanAll(dependsOn: ['cleanCommon', 'cleanCrawler', 'cleanPortlet']) { 
}
```

It's so verbose. Is there some way I could do something like the pseudo code below?

```
taskCleanAll {
    GradleBuild.pleaseRunTask('common/build.gradle', 'clean')
    GradleBuild.pleaseRunTask('crawler/build.gradle', 'clean')
    GradleBuild.pleaseRunTask('portlet/build.gradle', 'clean')
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot invoke a task directly, but there are plenty of other ways to abstract over the code. For example:

```
def createBuildTask(name, buildFile) {
    task "$name"(type: GradleBuild) {
        buildFile = buildFile
        tasks = ['clean']
    }
}  

createBuildTask("cleanCommon", "common/build.gradle")
createBuildTask("cleanCrawler", "crawler/build.gradle")
createBuildTask("cleanPortlet", "portlet/build.gradle")
```

I wonder why you use the `GradleBuild` task in the first place, but that's a different discussion.

Comment: I have three separate projects that don't know anything about each other and I just wanted to create a build file that can build them all in one go.

Comment: I wonder if you would be well-served to look into a multi-project build.

Answer (score 1):

```
def List buildFileList = ['common/build.gradle', 'crawler/build.gradle', 'portlet/build.gradle']

task cleanAll << {
    buildFileList.each() {
        def tempTask = tasks.create(name: "execute_$it", type: GradleBuild)
        tempTask.buildFile="$it"
        tempTask.tasks = ['clean']
        tempTask.execute()
    }
}
```

Comment: While this maybe can answer the question, it's better to provide some explanations about how this code help.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work... Note this is not tested. But why do you think it is so verbose? I think its rather clean like that.

```
task cleanAll << {
  StartParameter startParameter = project.gradle.startParameter.newBuild()
  startParameter.tasks = ['clean']
  runGradle('portlet/build.gradle', startParameter)
  runGradle('crawler/build.gradle', startParameter)
  runGradle('common/build.gradle', startParameter)
}

def runGradle(buildFile, params) {
  params.buildFile = buildFile
  GradleLauncher.newInstance(params).run().rethrowFailure();
}
```

Another option would be to extract the task creation:

```
task cleanAll
def createCleanTask(name) {
  task "${name}Clean"(type: GradleBuild) {
    tasks = ['clean']
    buildFile = "${name}/build.gradle"
  }
  cleanAll.dependsOn("${name}Clean")
}

createCleanTask("crawler")
createCleanTask("portlet")
createCleanTask("common")
```